# Creating a nested document in mongoDB using spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

**What I get**

This is what I get saved in mongoDB, in the Dialog Collection

```
"_id": "5a61c7c7d5981a4b88b5fe17",
"_class": "com.kalsym.next.gen.campaign.data.Dialog",
"message": {
    "title": "Welcome Message",
    "subTitle": "Click SUbscribe to avail the offer",
    "url": "www.hotmail.com"
},
"options": [{
    "IR": "Thanks for subscription",
    "value": "sub",
    "path": "sub"
},
{
    "IR": "www.kalsym.com/NoThanks",
    "value": "NoThnks",
    "path": "NT"
}]
```

**What I want:**

```
"_id": "5a4e16547d4cea1604bf28f8",
"message": {
    "Title": "",
    "SubTitle": "Do you want to talk to CSR?",
    "URL": ""
},
"options": {
    "Yes": {
        "IR": "You will get a callback within 1 hour, thanks.",
        "value": "Yes",
        "path": "NT\\NotNow\\Yes"
    },
    "No": {
        "IR": "No Problem, have a good day!",
        "value": "No",
        "path": "NT\\NotNow\\No"
    }
}
```

The issue is with the Options field. I want it to be a key value pair, not as a simple list.

This is my Dialog class:

```
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Getter     
@Setter
@Document(collection = "Dialog")
public class Dialog {
    @Id
    public String id;
    private Message message;
    private List<Option> options;

    public Dialog(final Message message, final List<Option> options) {
        this.message = message;
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

this is the Message class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Message {

    private String title;
    private String subTitle;
    private String url;

    public Message(final String title, final String subTitle, final String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
        this.url = url;
        }

}
```

this is the option class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Option {
    private String IR;
    private String value;
    private String path;

    public Option(final String IR, final String value, final String path) {
        this.IR = IR;
        this.value = value;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Here is how I am saving it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = DialogRepository.class)
public class CampaignAPI implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private DialogRepository dialogRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CampaignAPI.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        Message msg = new Message("Welcome Message", "Click SUbscribe to avail the offer", "www.hotmail.com");
        final Option subscribe = new Option("Thanks for subscription", "sub", "sub");
        final Option noThanks = new Option("www.kalsym.com/NoThanks", "NoThnks", "NT");
        List<Option> options = Arrays.asList(subscribe, noThanks);

        final Dialog welcomeDialog = new Dialog(msg, options);
        dialogRepository.save(welcomeDialog);

    }
}
```

**My Question**

1. Is there something wrong in how I am expecting it to be saved? i.e. Is the schema correct? (Wanting a to save key/value pair in options Object)
2. Even if it is wrong, how do I save it exactly like the expected mongo document I have pasted above.

Comment: Your 1st option is "subscribe" instead of "yes". Your case is you want to serialize a list. Elements of list dont have key/value pair. They have just order.

Comment: yeah, so I don't have to create a list? in that case how can have this dynamic-ness.

Comment: Have you tried using Map<String, Option> ? Does it change anything ? Anyways, you should be using List<Option> to create an embedded array as oppose to named key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce expected JSON.

`public class Dialog { 
        @Id public String id; 
        private Message message;
        private Option Yes; 
        private Option No;
}`

Elements of List don't have key, they only have value and place in memory. This is why you don't want List.

Comment: thanks but the thing is, I dont want the options Yes and No all the time, in some other document they could go like "ok" and "cancel". So I want it to be dynamic